# Arduino Master-Slave Pin

Tags: arduino, pins

Can I change the pins on the communication for a Master-Slave arduino Wire transmission?  I want to communicate between 2 arduinos, but on one of them A4&A5 are taken

Comment: I would suggest asking this on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the pins used for I2C. They are hard wired to the ATmega chip's TWI hardware implementation (SDA + SCL). See [Wire Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/WireLibraryDetailedReference) and [Two Wire Serial Interface](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2564.pdf)